# Gradle settings not syncing

Tags: java, android

I have changed some of my gradle setting however I am getting an error stating that there is a version conflict however there is no errors in the code

```
app build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'


implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'


implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ERROR:

Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.1.

Product level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files


    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you show your product level build.gradle?

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version? 4.0.1 instead of 3.1.2 ?

Comment: In your project level build.gradle, edit classpath dependency of Google services to version 3.2.1. Like this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'` and then sync gradle again. It might ask you to update gradle dependency version to 3.1.3 in order to use latest version of google services.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham I have and it works however certain things like uploading to the firebase does not work since i've updated so I've tried to revert back to an older version to see if it'll work then I got that error

Answer (score 0):

In project level build.gradle, change google services version from `3.1.2` to `4.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
```

Change into

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1 and so on..